# Reloading Supersized! Slideshow transition Bug

Tags: jquery, supersized

I have an issue with using the Supersized! Plugin and replacing the images. The issue I am having is that the transitions from slide to slide gets exponentially faster when I reload the Slideshow.

To replicate the problem, click the projects navigation, then the sub menu item and it loads the next slide show, each time you click on one its skips more slides with each transition.

Here is the site http://www.liquidvision.co.uk/clients/wattsconstruction/

Here is the main code that is effected:

I Create the Image Arrays:

```
var homeImages = [  
                    {image : 'img/1.jpg', title : '', thumb : 'img/thumbs/1.jpg', url : ''},
                    {image : 'img/2.jpg', title : '', thumb : 'img/thumbs/2.jpg', url : ''},
                    {image : 'img/3.jpg', title : '', thumb : 'img/thumbs/3.jpg', url : ''},
                    ];

var home = $.makeArray(homeImages);

var secondImages = [    
                    {image : 'img/4.jpg', title : '', thumb : 'img/thumbs/4.jpg', url : ''},
                    {image : 'img/5.jpg', title : '', thumb : 'img/thumbs/5.jpg', url : ''},
                    {image : 'img/6.jpg', title : '', thumb : 'img/thumbs/6.jpg', url : ''},
                    ];

var second = $.makeArray(secondImages);
```

Then set the home page Supersized slideshow

```
$.supersized({

    // Functionality
    slideshow               :   1,          // Slideshow on/off
    autoplay                :   1,          // Slideshow starts playing automatically
    start_slide             :   0,          // Start slide (0 is random)
    stop_loop               :   0,          // Pauses slideshow on last slide
    random                  :   0,          // Randomize slide order (Ignores start slide)
    slide_interval          :   3000,       // Length between transitions
    transition              :   1,          // 0-None, 1-Fade, 2-Slide Top, 3-Slide Right, 4-Slide Bottom, 5-Slide Left, 6-Carousel Right, 7-Carousel Left
    transition_speed        :   500,        // Speed of transition
    new_window              :   1,          // Image links open in new window/tab
    pause_hover             :   0,          // Pause slideshow on hover
    keyboard_nav            :   1,          // Keyboard navigation on/off
    performance             :   1,          // 0-Normal, 1-Hybrid speed/quality, 2-Optimizes image quality, 3-Optimizes transition speed // (Only works for Firefox/IE, not Webkit)
    image_protect           :   1,          // Disables image dragging and right click with Javascript

    // Size & Position                         
    min_width               :   0,          // Min width allowed (in pixels)
    min_height              :   0,          // Min height allowed (in pixels)
    vertical_center         :   1,          // Vertically center background
    horizontal_center       :   1,          // Horizontally center background
    fit_always              :   0,          // Image will never exceed browser width or height (Ignores min. dimensions)
    fit_portrait            :   0,          // Portrait images will not exceed browser height
    fit_landscape           :   0,          // Landscape images will not exceed browser width

    // Components                           
    slide_links             :   'blank',    // Individual links for each slide (Options: false, 'num', 'name', 'blank')
    thumb_links             :   1,          // Individual thumb links for each slide
    thumbnail_navigation    :   0,          // Thumbnail navigation
    slides                  :   home        // Using the home Image array we created

});
```

Then create the restSupersized function:

```
function resetSupersized(arr)
{   

    $("#play-button").empty().remove();
    $("#thumb-list").empty().remove();
    $("#thumb-back").empty().remove();
    $("#thumb-forward").empty().remove();


    $("#supersized").fadeOut('fast', function() 
    {

        $('#supersized-loader').empty().remove();
        $('#supersized').empty().remove();
        $('#hzDownscaled').empty().remove();
        $('body').append('<div id="supersized-loader"></div><ul id="supersized"></ul>');


        // Animation complete.
        $("#tray-button").fadeIn();
        $('#thumb-tray').html('<div id="thumb-back"></div><div id="thumb-forward"></div>');

        $.supersized({
           // Functionality
           slideshow            :   1,          // Slideshow on/off
           autoplay             :   1,          // Slideshow starts playing automatically
           start_slide          :   1,          // Start slide (0 is random)
           stop_loop            :   0,          // Pauses slideshow on last slide
           random               :   0,          // Randomize slide order (Ignores start slide)
           slide_interval       :   3000,       // Length between transitions
           transition           :   1,          // 0-None, 1-Fade, 2-Slide Top, 3-Slide Right, 4-Slide Bottom, 5-Slide Left, 6-Carousel Right, 7-Carousel Left
           transition_speed     :   500,        // Speed of transition
           new_window           :   1,          // Image links open in new window/tab
           pause_hover          :   0,          // Pause slideshow on hover
           keyboard_nav         :   1,          // Keyboard navigation on/off
           performance          :   1,          // 0-Normal, 1-Hybrid speed/quality, 2-Optimizes image quality, 3-Optimizes transition speed // (Only works for Firefox/IE, not Webkit)
           image_protect        :   1,          // Disables image dragging and right click with Javascript

           // Size & Position                          
           min_width            :   0,          // Min width allowed (in pixels)
           min_height           :   0,          // Min height allowed (in pixels)
           vertical_center      :   1,          // Vertically center background
           horizontal_center    :   1,          // Horizontally center background
           fit_always           :   0,          // Image will never exceed browser width or height (Ignores min. dimensions)
           fit_portrait         :   0,          // Portrait images will not exceed browser height
           fit_landscape        :   0,          // Landscape images will not exceed browser width

           // Components                            
            slide_links         :   'blank',    // Individual links for each slide (Options: false, 'num', 'name', 'blank')
            thumb_links         :   1,          // Individual thumb links for each slide
            thumbnail_navigation:   0,          // Thumbnail navigation
            slides              :   arr

        });     



    });

}
```

Then call the function with the array I want to use... i.e. onClick();

```
resetSupersized(second);
```

Thanks for your help ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Do not know if this answer is still valid for you. I was looking for a solution for this two and turns around it's quite simple if you look into you html before and after you load you gallery.

What this gallery does is fill an `<ul>` element with your images...and everytime you reload your gallery it adds more pictures to it instead of removing.

I suppose that the first time your gallery seems alright, when you fadeOut just be sure to empty your gallery div too, like this:

`$('#supersized').html('');`

Comment: I tried this toasted by filling the Supersized again. But the javascript will not apply prevslide / activeslide classes the proper way so it will not loop the gallery.